# Указатель на метод класса

Tags: c++, указатели

Требуется сделать указатель на метод. В данном случае есть ряд методов с одинаковым объявлением. Здесь все они находятся в `public`.

Указатель на метод называется `Metric`.

Компилятор ругается на помеченную строку. Сообщение:

> ошибка: cannot convert 'std::vector (CTesting::*)()' to 'std::vector (*)()' in assignment
>     this->Metric = &this->ExTimeofWork;

Судя по всему что-то с пространством имён. Я пытался его явно указывать в месте вызова метода. Не получается. Если подобную конструкцию делать вне класса, то всё хорошо.

Объясните пожалуйста, за счёт каких механизмов возникает данная ошибка? Как её исправить?

```
class CTesting
{
    private:
        // code     
        vector<double> ( *Metric)();

    public:


        vector<double> ExTimeofWork();
        vector<double> ExTimeGenerationToAccept();
        vector<double> ExTimePoolToAccept();
        vector<double> ExMaxTimeGenerationToAccept();
        vector<double> ExMaxTimePoolToAccept();

        vector<double> GetTimeGenerationToAccept();
        vector<double> GetTimePoolToAccept();
        vector<double> GetTimeofWork();
};

void CTesting::Execute()
{
    this->Metric = &this->ExTimeofWork; //Ошибка!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    //... Code

    //...
    return;
}
```

Comment: Указатель на метод класса? У вас есть какое-то внятное объяснение почему вы хотите использовать его вместо виртуальной функции?

Comment: Каким образом это сделать с помощью виртуальной функции? Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Этот класс очень странен, лучше расскажите что он должен делать и кто-то подскажет по изящнее решение. Судя по всему там какие-то замеры времени выполнения чего-то.

Comment: Проклятые кресты. От абстрактной метрики наследуются частные, После чего пользователь создает у себя вектор из нужных частных и для всех них вызывает виртуальный метод `execute()` (Который у каждой частной метрики переопределен по своему `ExTimeofWork`, `ExTimeGenerationToAccept`, `ExTimePoolToAccept` и.т.д.) одной строкой в цикле. А с указателями плохой вариант, длинно и не читабельно. Расписывать лень, кто-нибудь сделает это наверняка.

Comment: @igumnov: Попробовал объяснить вашу идею в ответе.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Вы путаете указатель на функцию и указатель на функцию-член, это [разные вещи](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types).

Попробуйте определить `Metric` так:

```
vector<double> (CTesting::*Metric)();
```

Соответственно присвоение должно выглядеть как

```
this->Metric = &CTesting::ExTimeofWork;
```

а вызов —

```
(this->*Metric)();
```

Да, это странный синтаксис, ничего не поделаешь.

---

Идея, которую описал @igumnov в комментариях, такова. Вам не нужно объединять в классе `CTesting` все возможные варианты поведения. Делайте не union всех возможных метрик, а разбейте на случаи и применяйте композицию.

```
abstract class CTesting
{
    CTestingData* data;

public:
    virtual vector<double> Metric() = 0;
};

class CExTimeofworkTesting : public CTesting
{
public:
    vector<double> Metric() override
    {
        // тут содержимое ExTimeofWork()
    }
};

class CExTimeGenerationToAcceptTesting : public CTesting
{
public:
    vector<double> Metric() override
    {
        // тут содержимое ExTimeGenerationToAccept()
    }
};
```

Не забудьте отделить общие данные в класс `CTestingData`. Теперь ваш код будет просто таким:

```
vector<CTesting*> testings =
{
    new CExTimeofworkTesting(data),
    new CExMaxTimePoolToAcceptTesting(data)
    // ...
};

for (auto t : testings)
    t->Metric();
```

Таким образом, у вас простые классы, меньше проблем с расширяемостью, разделение ответственности, и обыкновенная виртуальная функция. Профит!

Comment: О да об этом я и говорил, спасибо @Vlad Теперь хоть это и правда похоже на С++, а не на сишника который зачем-то взялся на них писать. Плюсанул.

Comment: D:\Job\Acronis\TestProblem\EmulationOfDisk\Emulate\CTesting.cpp:5: ошибка: undefined reference to `CTesting::ExTimeofWork()'

Comment: @hedgehogues: Покажите текущий код.

Comment: @VladD, посмотрите комментарий ниже. Код ровно такой же

Comment: @VladD, спасибо большое, разобрался. У меня не было объявлено тела функции.

Comment: @VladD вопрос в следующем, почему нужно определять именно так: vector<double> (CTesting::*Metric)();, а не, вот так: vector<double> (*CTesting::Metric)();? Зачем здесь указывать пространство имён? Этот метод внутри класса же находится. Аналогичный вопрос тут: this->Metric = &CTesting::ExTimeofWork;, а не this->Metric = CTesting::&ExTimeofWork;. Можно ли это как-то объяснить?

Comment: @hedgehogues: Это ж не пространство имён, это имя класса. Почему такой синтаксис — это не ко мне, это комитет по стандартизации так постановил.

Answer (score 8):

Указатель на метод != указатель на функцию. Внутри оно несколько сложнее устроено. Как минимум метод класса подразумевает неявный аргумент - `this`. Ну и вид у него другой:

```
void (Type::*)()
```

И вызов производится иначе:

```
(objectPtr->*proc)()
```

И вообще, VladD отличный FAQ вспомнил на эту тему: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

В вашем случае как-то так:

```
class CTesting
{
    private:
        //code      
        //vector<double> ( *Metric)();
        vector<double> (CTesting::*Metric)();

    public:


        vector<double> ExTimeofWork(){}
        vector<double> ExTimeGenerationToAccept(){}
        vector<double> ExTimePoolToAccept(){}
        vector<double> ExMaxTimeGenerationToAccept(){}
        vector<double> ExMaxTimePoolToAccept(){}

        vector<double> GetTimeGenerationToAccept(){}
        vector<double> GetTimePoolToAccept(){}
        vector<double> GetTimeofWork(){}

        void Execute();
};

void CTesting::Execute()
{
    this->Metric = &CTesting::ExTimeofWork; 
    //... Code

    //...

    (this->*Metric)();

    return;
}
```

А если нужно-то как-то абстрагироваться, используйте свои функторы, или делегаты типа `std::function` или `boost::function` вместе с `std::bind` или `boost::bind`

UPD: чуть подправил по комментариям.

Comment: Вот такая ошибка: D:\Job\Acronis\TestProblem\EmulationOfDisk\Emulate\CTesting.cpp:5: ошибка: undefined reference to `CTesting::ExTimeofWork()'

Comment: @hedgehogues: Ну, а функция `CTesting::ExTimeofWork` у вас в .cpp определена?

Comment: @VladD Все таки Nofate [оказался прав в том былинном комментарии.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23930992#23930992)

Comment: @igumnov: Пошёл поставить звёздочку комментарию, обнаружил, что она уже там есть :)

Answer (score 7):

Вот демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как функции могут быть вызваны

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class CTesting
{
private:
//    std::vector<double> ( CTesting::*Metric)();

public:
    std::vector<double> ExTimeofWork() { return { 1.1 }; }
    std::vector<double> ExTimeGenerationToAccept() { return { 2.2 }; }
    std::vector<double> ExTimePoolToAccept() { return { 3.3 }; }
    std::vector<double> ExMaxTimeGenerationToAccept() { return { 4.4 }; }
    std::vector<double> ExMaxTimePoolToAccept() { return { 5.5 }; }

    std::vector<double> GetTimeGenerationToAccept() { return { 6.6 }; }
    std::vector<double> GetTimePoolToAccept() { return { 7.7 }; }
    std::vector<double> GetTimeofWork() { return { 8.8 }; }
    void Execute()
    {
        for ( std::vector<double> ( CTesting::*Metric)() : 
             { 
                 &CTesting::ExTimeofWork, 
                 &CTesting::ExTimeGenerationToAccept, 
                 &CTesting::ExTimePoolToAccept,
                 &CTesting::ExMaxTimeGenerationToAccept,
                 &CTesting::ExMaxTimePoolToAccept,
                 &CTesting::GetTimeGenerationToAccept,
                 &CTesting::GetTimePoolToAccept,
                 &CTesting::GetTimeofWork
             } )
        {
            std::cout << (this->*Metric)().front() << std::endl;
        }           
    }       
};

int main()
{
    CTesting().Execute();
}
```

Вывод программы

```
1.1
2.2
3.3
4.4
5.5
6.6
7.7
8.8
```

Или если использовать член данных - указатель, то функция может выглядеть следующим образом

```
class CTesting
{
private:
    std::vector<double> ( CTesting::*Metric)();

public:
    std::vector<double> ExTimeofWork() { return { 1.1 }; }
    //...
    void Execute()
    {
        Metric = &CTesting::ExTimeofWork, 
        std::cout << ( this->*Metric )().front() << std::endl;
    }       
};
```

Если в этом выражении

```
( this->*Metric )()
```

не использовать скобки и записать как

```
this->*Metric()
```

то оно будет интерпретироваться как

```
this->*( Metric() )
```

так как постфиксное выражение вызова функции `Metric()` имеет более высокий приоритет, чем операторы обращения к указателям на члены класса

Ниже представлен пример, демонстрирующий это различие

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class CTesting
{
private:
    std::vector<double> ( CTesting::*Metric)();

public:
    std::vector<double> ExTimeofWork() { return { 1.1 }; }
    //...
    void Execute()
    {
        Metric = &CTesting::ExTimeofWork, 
        std::cout << ( this->*Metric )().front() << std::endl;
        std::cout << ( this->*GetMemberFunctionPointer() )().front() << std::endl;
    }       
    std::vector<double> (CTesting::*GetMemberFunctionPointer() )()
    {
        return &CTesting::ExTimeofWork;
    }       
};

int main()
{
    CTesting().Execute();
}
```

Можно сравнить два вызова

```
std::cout << ( this->*Metric )().front() << std::endl;
std::cout << ( this->*GetMemberFunctionPointer() )().front() <<
```

Во втором вызове. то есть в вызове с функцией `GetMemberFunctionPointer` скобки вокруг `this->*GetMemberFunctionPointer` отсутствуют. Поэтмоу сначала будет вызвана функции `GetMemberFunctionPointer()`, а к ее результату применен  оператор обращения к указателю на члены класса.